# Shared Endpoint URL in Websphere Portal

Tags: web-services, websphere, webservice-client, websphere-portal

What is the best way to share the endpoint urls of webservices in websphere?  We have all the webservice clients in a shared library so that they are accessible to all the wars and portlets.  We currently have a mix of property files and portlet preferences setup with the endpoints to the webservices, but we would like a way where we can change the endpoint only once and all apps see the change.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Portal, only WAS, but can you refer to a [URL Resource Reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tjtc_uovr.html)?